# Add functionality of one button inside another one

Tags: c#, xaml

I have two buttons in a C# xaml project. The first button has the play functionality and the second one has the stop functionality.

How can I add the stop functionality inside the play button? Is this possible to add the functionality of one button inside another?

Comment: What if you hide 'Play' button on its click and show 'Hide' button in its place? Do you think its one way to achieve?

Comment: use if else statements

Comment: By assuming that the stop functionality is contained in `public void stop()` and the start one in `public void start()`, you might call any of these methods from the event of the button (`btnStartStop`). You might change the text displayed in that button every time (e.g., "run"/"stop") and decide what to do inside the click event on account of this property (i.e., if the text is "run" call `start()`, otherwise call `stop()`). What you are asking is very simple, but also admits many solutions (+ you are not sharing your code). All this seems quite offtopic.

Comment: How can i check if the stop button is clicked inside the if @Scriven. Siva  Gopal I am not sure if I catch what you suggested.

Comment: @varocarbs my issue is that the stop functionality has to be in play button not in itself.

Comment: You could use a bool or something similar to track which button was hit last. So if you click play the bool playing will be set to true, if you click it again it will hit a statement that will set it to false

Comment: @snakeplissken Please check on Toggle button, if that can help you.

Comment: (my nick is varocarbas) My comment is quite clear (unlikely your question and your second comment "in play button not in itself"?! What do you mean with that?). There are many alternatives and general talking is usually considered off-topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a button Image from Play to Pause when clicked using an Ellipse template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216047/changing-a-button-image-from-play-to-pause-when-clicked-using-an-ellipse-templat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [`ToggleButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton(v=vs.110).aspx) for this purpose:

```
<ToggleButton Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"></ToggleButton>
```

And:

```
private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Play(); // Call Play method
}

private void ToggleButton_OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stop(); // Call Stop method
}
```

Or:

```
<ToggleButton Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></ToggleButton>
```

And:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if ((bool)(sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked)
     {
          Play(); // Call Play method
     }
     else
     {
          Stop(); // Call Stop method
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to add both buttons on the same grid cell, with same layout properties.

Bind the "IsVisible" property of the button to the Boolean flag in your view model(like IsPlaying) using boolean to visibility converter. You will be knowing the state of playback in the view model. For the other button do the same with inverse boolean value.

Hope it helps.